# What is the best field definition to store a .NET decimal into MySQL?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, decimal, precision

I need to store decimals into MySQL, which can have a varying precision. Therefore I would be interested to know which MySQL field type is absolutely equivalent to .NET's [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) structure, if any.

I plan to use [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) as a lightweight ORM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .net decimal can be different datatypes under the hood.

```
.net formats                                  MySQL
----------------------------------------------------
Decimal(Double)                              Float
Decimal(Int32)                               DECIMAL
Decimal(Int32())                             DECIMAL
Decimal(Int64)                               DECIMAL
Decimal(Single)                              DECIMAL
Decimal(UInt32)                              DECIMAL
Decimal(UInt64)                              DECIMAL
Decimal(Int32, Int32, Int32, Boolean, Byte)  DECIMAL
//This is really a UINT96.
```

**Warning**
Note that according to Jon Skeet, `decimal` can be declared in lots of ways, but will always be a `FLOAT` under the hood, with all the rounding errors that brings, you have been warned.
See: [SQL decimal equivalent in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674506/sql-decimal-equivalent-in-net/7674549#7674549)

MySQL's `DECIMAL` takes up more space if you assign it a larger precision.

From the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html

> Values for DECIMAL columns in MySQL 5.5 are stored using a binary format that packs nine decimal digits into 4 bytes.

The largest number of digits is 65, divided by 9 = 8 bytes, an INT128.

Comment: Thanks, so for the "standard" .NET decimal, which one would be most appropriate? In .NET the scale is not fixed AFAIK, contrarily to MySQL.

Comment: @erwin, The scale is not fixed in MySQL either, it's just an approximation.

Comment: MSDN says decimal has 28-29 significant digits (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx), while on MySQL doc there are two arguments when creating a decimal field (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html), where the scale is fixed. Am I missing something?

Comment: @erwin, The first number is the number of significant digits, the second is a display hint, how many of those digits are behind the decimal separator. decimal(10,3) can hold `9999999.999` max, DECIMAL(10,9) can hold 9.999999999 max. Same precision but different presentation.

Comment: yes but in .NET decimal only the significant digits matter, not the decimals: for example a field with a format of DECIMAL(5,2) holds values from -999.99 up to 999.99, it won't hold 1234 even though there are less than 4 significant digits.

Comment: @Erwin, you've got it. Just choose the precision large enough to hold the values you need.

Comment: .NET decimal *can't* be different datatypes under the hood. It can take different values in its constructor, but the value itself is *always* a floating decimal point type.