# SQL decimal equivalent in .NET

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server

What is the **SQL** (MS SQL Server) `Decimal` equivalent in **.NET**?

Should it be `Double`, `Decimal` or `Float` (`Single` in VB.NET)?

Comment: `Decimal` since `Double` might loose precision...

Comment: @Yahia Depending on the usage, Decimal might be the one that loses precision. The principal difference is that Decimal is base 10 and Double is binary. Granted Decimal is commonly used for currency work and so precision is seldom an issue.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Actually, if the source is DECIMAL, converting to a FLOAT is where you risk losing precision.

Comment: @Dems If the source is decimal right. And it will be here. Fair cop. All I meant to point out is that decimal does not have more precision that floating point per se.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's no *exact* equivalent type in .NET, as SQL's decimal type is fixed point, whereas .NET's `System.Decimal` type is a floating (decimal) point type.

However, `System.Decimal` is definitely the closest match, and should generally be what's used to represent the value stored in a decimal column in a SQL database.

Comment: Decimal, however, is not a "common" type four floating values, because of the (exceeded) precision. Personally I use Double more often... But in order to map corresponding values... I think I will go with Decimals...

Comment: @serhio: Actually I think most business apps should probably use `decimal` more often than `double`. The precision isn't the important thing - it's the nature of the data and the *base* of the type. If you're storing a manmade quantity, decimal is likely to be the right approach. For "natural" values such as height and width, `double` is more appropriate.

Comment: @Jonskeet, are you sure about that? This article begs to differ with you: http://gregs-blog.com/2007/12/10/dot-net-decimal-type-vs-float-type/

Comment: @Johan: Which part of the article differs with which of my statements?

Comment: I looked up the .net decimal a while ago and found this table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348593/what-is-the-best-field-definition-to-store-a-net-decimal-into-mysql/7349064#7349064  I now regret not putting in a link to the MS-article I copy pasted that table from. It says you can declare decimal like so: `Decimal(Int32)`

Comment: @Johan: It's not at all clear what that table means... but however you create a `System.Decimal`, it is *always* a floating decimal point value. I disagree with that answer, basically.

Answer (score 12):

Use `Decimal`, as can be seen in [this table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx).